# Compare all files with all files, loop in loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I need to write a program, make a list of files, compare them and check which words they have in common, so I need a loop in a loop in a loop in a loop cause I need to check all files with all files. I don't need the code but I need just help on how I can make a list of the files it can be like 100 files or 3 etc can someone help me please?

Write a program that accepts two or more filenames and prints out the names of the two files that have the most words in common.

Comment: Do  you have any code you can show? If you can show your code and what you are having trouble with, you can get some guidance on what to do next or correct you if there is something that you aren't doing right.

Comment: Your question is too generic! Be more precise.

Comment: You need to show your work and effort before asking for help on what sounds like a *homework* assignment. Also, if you don't know how to create a loop in python, you should consider using a tutorial first.

Comment: It really does sound like a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, littleboy, you do not need loop in a loop in a loop in a loop in a loop.

You need to read file-by-file, that's one loop, and make checksum of each. What it will be (word count in a dictionary most probably) it is on you to decide. You store these checksums in a list.

Then you iterate through that list comparing the current checksum by all others.

That is loop in a loop - O(n***2).

All other loops that might be used shouldn't be nested or have to be pushed into functions.

Never the less, this is a demanding algorithm, if not computationally, then memoricly. (if there are a lot of files and/or they are big).

With such algorithms there is always a compromise about what to use more. Memory or processor.